# Prove that $\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}=\delta_{ik}$

Tags: real-analysis, tensors, kronecker-delta, kronecker-symbol

Firstly, I should mention that I have just started learning about tensors, the problem is that I need to understand why the result $$\fbox{$\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}=\delta_{ik}$}\tag{1}$$ is true in order to be able to follow certain proofs given in my lecture course.

Before starting tensors I was taught that 
$$\delta_{ij} = \begin{cases}
0, & \mbox{if } i \ne j  \\
1, & \mbox{if } i=j \end{cases}\tag{2}$$

But now that I have been introduced to tensors I have been told that the Kronecker delta can actually be thought of as a tensor and that

$$\delta_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix}\delta _{11}&\delta _{12}&\delta _{13}\\\delta _{21}&\delta _{22}&\delta _{23}\\\delta _{31}&\delta _{32}&\delta _{33}\end{bmatrix}$$
for $i=1,2,3$ and $j=1,2,3$.

Using the definition in $\mathrm(2)$ then 
$$\delta_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}=I$$

I know that in $\mathrm(1)$ the Einstein summation convention is being used such that 
$$\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}=\sum_{j=1}^{3}\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}$$

But if I try to prove $(1)$ as follows

$$\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}=\begin{bmatrix}\delta _{11}&\delta _{12}&\delta _{13}\\\delta _{21}&\delta _{22}&\delta _{23}\\\delta _{31}&\delta _{32}&\delta _{33}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\delta _{11}&\delta _{12}&\delta _{13}\\\delta _{21}&\delta _{22}&\delta _{23}\\\delta _{31}&\delta _{32}&\delta _{33}\end{bmatrix}$$
for $i=1,2,3$ and $j=1,2,3$ and $k=1,2,3$.

It doesn't bother me to multiply this whole thing out if it helps my understanding, but frankly, I don't see the point as

$$\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}=I^2=I \ne \delta_{ik}$$

I have already watched this:
[Why does $\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}=\delta_{ik}\,$ An explanation to make sense!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mi-vaAh774k)  which does *not* explain why $\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}=\delta_{ik}$

I have also looked at a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906332/prove-ell-ki-ell-kj-delta-ij) on this site but the answer is too complicated for me to understand.

---

So to summarize, is there a simple way of showing that $$\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}=\delta_{ik}?$$

Comment: In what way is $I^2$ different from $I$?

Comment: But you know $I^2=I$, right?

Comment: @Arthur They are the same, I know this

Comment: But then you have $I^2=\delta_{ik}$, don't you?

Comment: @jgon Yes I know that, but how does it prove the result?

Comment: @BLAZE What is the matrix representation of $\delta_{ik}$?

Comment: @Arthur It's that simple? Assuming that $i,j,k$ are dummy indices.

Comment: @BLAZE Yep, that's it.

Comment: @Travis Okay, thanks I got it now, feel like the question is a bit obsolete now.

Comment: @BLAZE You can always write your own answer if you understand it now.

Comment: Thinking longhand about tensors rather than matrices, the products are zero (one of the factors is zero) unless $i=j=k$. There is an implied sum over the index $j$ - a sum of three terms for each choice of $i$ and $k$ with $j=1,2,3$. If $i\neq k$ then all the products are zero and their sum is zero. If $i=k$ then the term for $j=i=k$ will be $1$ and the other choices for $j$ will give zero and the sum will be $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone struggles to gain intuition with this.  The way I came to realize it was to think about the terms in $\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}$.

$\delta_{ij}$ is zero unless $i=j$, and $\delta_{jk}$ is zero unless $j=k$.  So for any $j$, $\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}$ (no summation) is $1$ if $i$, $j$, and $k$ are equal, and $0$ otherwise.

Now $i$, $j$, and $k$ are all being drawn from the same pool of cartesian indices.  So when we do sum over all $j$'s, exactly one of those $j$'s will agree with $i$, and exactly one will agree with $k$.  If $j$ agrees with $i$ at the same time it agrees with $k$ (that is, all three indices are equal), we will pick up a $1$.  For all the rest, we're summing up zeroes.  In other words, the sum is $1$ if $i=k$, and $0$ otherwise.  That tensor is $\delta_{ik}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So by extension I may write $\delta_{ab}\delta_{bc}\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}=\delta_{ik}=\delta_{ab}=\delta_{ba}=\delta_{ib} = I$? Or, in other words, any no. of Kronecker deltas multiplied together will *always* be the identity matrix, right?

Comment: @BLAZE: No, that is only true if the tensors are connected via matrix multiplication. In your expression you only have Einstein summation over $b$ and $j$, so a 4-tensor remains, $$δ_{ab}δ_{bc}δ_{ij}δ_{jk}=δ_{ac}δ_{ik}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}$ denotes a multiplication on the index j. $\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}=\delta_{i1}\delta_{1k}+\delta_{i2}\delta_{2k}+\delta_{i3}\delta_{3k}$. If $i\neq 1$ and $k\neq 1$ for the first term, then the first term will be zero. Similarly  If $i\neq 2$ and $k\neq 2$ for the second term, then the second term will be zero. Therefore $\delta_{ij}\delta_{jk}=\delta_{11}\delta_{11}+\delta_{22}\delta_{22}+\delta_{33}\delta_{33}=\delta_{ik}$.